# history.js infinite event loop

Tags: jquery, history.js, html5-history

I have a problem with history.js

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

The event onload in line 3170 is in a infinite loop

What is this event for and what triggers it?!

It's only in Chrome I experience this problem

```
/**
         * Bind for Saving Store
         */
        if ( sessionStorage ) {
            // When the page is closed
            History.onUnload = function(){    // <----- this is triggeren in a loop
                // Prepare
                var currentStore, item, currentStoreString;

                // Fetch
                try {
                    currentStore = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('History.store'))||{};
                }
                catch ( err ) {
                    currentStore = {};
                }
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue in latest Firefox. Have you ever been able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Not much after I've commented your question I've found the solution. There is an issue reported at History.js about this behaviour [here](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/321).

The main cause is a `setInterval` call, which is there due to IE8 limitations. The issue in the code is that it's applied in every case, not only for IE8.

Until it sometime gets fixed in the main project, this unnecessary polling can be fixed by editing the code of History.js around line #1992.

```
// For Internet Explorer
if (History.isInternetExplorer() && History.getInternetExplorerMajorVersion() < 9) {
  History.intervalList.push(setInterval(History.onUnload, History.options.storeInterval));
}
```